# Concatenating 0's in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns (first contains the value `0`, second contains the value `1`).

This statement returns `1`, and not `01`

```
Cells(1, 26).Value = CStr(Cells(1, 24).Value) & CStr(Cells(1, 25).Value)
```

I want to concatenate them in 3rd column to `01`. How do I do this?

Comment: For example: `Cells(1, 26).Value = "'" & Cells(1, 24).Value & Cells(1, 25).Value` Note, that MS Excel treats `01` as number. You have to add `'` on the beginning of statement to change it to string.

Comment: @MaciejLos, Thanks, That worked

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: Although I originally suggested prepending the `'` (@MaciejLos beat me by a few seconds :D), another possibility would be formatting the cell using a format of `"00"`.  It depends on whether you just want the cell to **look** like it is a two-digit number, or whether you really want the two-character string in the cell.

Comment: @YowE3K, That's solution is better than mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you put an integer value in a cell, the format is set to number.
You can use:

```
Cells(1, 26).NumberFormat = "@" 'This set cell format to Text
Cells(1, 26).Value = CStr(Cells(1, 24).Value) & CStr(Cells(1, 25).Value)
```

Comment: Why to use `CStr()` function if you say to Excel treat this content as string?

Comment: This is the the best approach. Format property should be used for formatting.Don't force literals to format the data..

Comment: @MaciejLos, as I understand, need to change 0 to String because if you concatenate 2 integers (0 & 1) your result will be 1 (0 will be lost).

Comment: @MaciejLos without `CStr` the type conversion still occurs, only implicitly. Prefer explicit type conversions and member calls (write code that says what it does *and does what it says*) - it works without `.Value` too, but omitting it would be an implicit member call; also `Cells` is implicitly referring to the `ActiveSheet` if this is in anywhere other than a workshet's code-behind, in which case proper qualification would be `Me.Cells`. FWIW this blows up with a *type mismatch* if any of the cells involved contains an error value.

Comment: If using VBA wouldn't it be better to just set `Cells(1, 26).NumberFormat = "00"` then transfer the true number value?

Comment: @Jeeped good point - depends if OP means to treat `04` as a string or as a number. IMO if the data isn't meant to be used for any arithmetics or as a numeric function parameter, then treating it as a string is semantically correct.